# simple draggable popup window with html5 does not move in chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i trying to implement simple not dependent on external libs draggable flouting window
the problem is that the window is created but it static and not draggable , it the same code i take from this reference web example : http://codelifter.com/main/javascript/dragablelayer.html:

this is all happening in the content script of charom extension:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('client.js');
s.onload = function() {
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
};

try{
(document.head||document.documentElement||document.body).appendChild(s);
}catch(e){
  console.log("exception in appendChild");
}
```

client.js:

```
isIE=document.all;
isNN=!document.all&&document.getElementById;
isN4=document.layers;
isHot=false;

function ddInit(e){
  topDog=isIE ? "BODY" : "HTML";
  whichDog=isIE ? document.all.theLayer : document.getElementById("theLayer");  
  hotDog=isIE ? event.srcElement : e.target;  
  while (hotDog.id!="titleBar"&&hotDog.tagName!=topDog){
    hotDog=isIE ? hotDog.parentElement : hotDog.parentNode;
  } 

  if (hotDog.id=="titleBar"){
    offsetx=isIE ? event.clientX : e.clientX;
    offsety=isIE ? event.clientY : e.clientY;
    nowX=parseInt(whichDog.style.left);
    nowY=parseInt(whichDog.style.top);
    ddEnabled=true;
    document.onmousemove=dd;
  }
}

function dd(e){
  //console.log("Starting draging");
  if (!ddEnabled) 
  {
    //console.log("continue draging !ddEnabled");
    return;
  }
  whichDog.style.left=isIE ? nowX+event.clientX-offsetx : nowX+e.clientX-offsetx; 
  whichDog.style.top=isIE ? nowY+event.clientY-offsety : nowY+e.clientY-offsety;
  return false;  
}

function ddN4(whatDog){
  if (!isN4) return;
  N4=eval(whatDog);
  N4.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN|Event.MOUSEUP);
  N4.onmousedown=function(e){
    N4.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
    N4x=e.x;
    N4y=e.y;
  }
  N4.onmousemove=function(e){
    if (isHot){
      N4.moveBy(e.x-N4x,e.y-N4y);
      return false;
    }
  }
  N4.onmouseup=function(){
    N4.releaseEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
  }
}

function hideMe(){
  if (isIE||isNN) whichDog.style.visibility="hidden";
  else if (isN4) document.theLayer.visibility="hide";
}

function showMe(){
  if (isIE||isNN) whichDog.style.visibility="visible";
  else if (isN4) document.theLayer.visibility="show";
}

try{
    console.log("Starting to create tabel");
    var layerNode= document.createElement('div');
    layerNode.setAttribute('id','theLayer');
    layerNode.style.position="absolute";
    layerNode.style.width="250px";
    layerNode.style.left="100";
    layerNode.style.top="100";
    layerNode.style.visibility="visible";

    var tableNode= document.createElement('table');
    tableNode.setAttribute('border','0');
    tableNode.setAttribute('width','250');
    tableNode.setAttribute('bgcolor','#424242');
    tableNode.setAttribute('cellspacing','0');
    tableNode.setAttribute('cellpadding','5');  
    var newRow = tableNode.insertRow();
    var oCell = newRow.insertCell();
    oCell.setAttribute('width','100%');
    oCell.innerHTML =  "<table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' height='36'><tr>"+
                      "<td id='titleBar' style='cursor:move' width='100%'>"+
                      "<ilayer width='100%' onSelectStart='return false'>"+
                      "<layer width='100%' onMouseover='isHot=true;if (isN4) ddN4(theLayer)' onMouseout='isHot=false'>"+
                      "<font face='Arial' color='#FFFFFF'>Layer Title</font></layer></ilayer></td>"+
                      "<td style='cursor:hand' valign='top'>"+
                      "<a href='#' onClick='hideMe();return false'><font color=#ffffff size=2 face=arial  style='text-decoration:none'>X</font></a></td></tr><tr>"+
                      "<td width='100%' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='padding:4px' colspan='2'>"+
                        "This is where your content goes.<br>"+
                        "It can be any html code or text.<br>"+
                        "Remember to feed the reindeer.<br>"+
                        "Avoid chewable giblet curtains."+
                      "</td></tr></table>";




    layerNode.appendChild(tableNode);
    document.body.appendChild(layerNode);

    document.onmousedown=ddInit;
    document.onmouseup=Function("ddEnabled=false");
    console.log("Ending to create tabel");
}
catch(e){
  console.log("script in page exception in appendChild"+e);
  //alert(e);
}
```

Comment: `||document.body` can be omitted, because the preceeding `document.documentElement` always exists. And, are you aware that your code is ancient (over 10 years or something)? Why are you using IE/Netscape-targeted code in a Chrome extension?

Comment: i tried to find simple minimal example on the web that doesn't use Jquery or such . but maybe its not such bad idea using jquery ...